# Can I declare and pass an object to a function in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, object

In JavaScript I can declare AND pass an object to a function as follows:

```
    passInObject({name: "myname", age: 34, height: 70});

    function passInObject(myObject) {
        var name = myObject.name;
        var age = myObject.age;
        var height = myObject.height;

        //do stuff with variables here
    }
```

Is there a way to do this in PHP? I'm still new and trying to wrap my brain around it through cross-language comparisons. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just cast an array to a StdClass object in your call to the function

```
passInObject((object) ['name' => 'myname', 'age' => 34, 'height' => 70]);
```

Comment: I would just leave it as an array instead of an object, unless there is a specific reason to use an object.

Comment: In php arrays are naturally very like JS objects already. If you want to have fixed fields you can use a specific class. Otherwise use arrays with string-keys and you are fine. Just don't do casting. It will only cause you trouble.